# Can Facebook's Requests Dialog work as a display:iframe or display:page?

Tags: facebook, dialog

All of Facebook's Dialogs examples show a page to redirect the user to in the form http:// www.facebook.com/dialog/xxx?yyy... EXCEPT the Requests Dialog, which shows examples using FB.UI() in the JavaScript SDK.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

My question, not addressed anywhere on the Facebook documentation, is can the requests dislog be accessed by directing the browser to http://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?...

I've been trying for hours, but I keep getting "Sorry, an error occurred." Am I doing it wrong or can it not be done?

Comment: Did you solve this? Please pick the correct answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i am able to solve it

you need to use URL like

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=URL_GIVEN_IN_APP/&message=abc

Its is working fine for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a request dialog behave as page directly, but you can use **XFBML** and `fb:request-form` into a, let's say, invite.php page into your app to create a request invitation form.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.xfbml.parse/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/serverFbml/

Comment: I've been encouraged not to use FBML or fb:serverFBML because it either won't work now or will be depreciated soon. Is there any other way to show the user a request form without using FB.UI()?

Comment: FBML is going to be deprecated, not XFBML. Take a look: http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/ If there's another way, I would like to know it too!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to debug this a lot.

The final code which seems to have worked once was

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?access_token=xxxx&api_key=xxxx&app_id=xxxx&display=iframe&frictionless=false&locale=en_US&message=abc&next=xxxx" frameborder="0">
```

I got this to work on one of the browsers, but when i try it in the other browser i consecutively keep getting the error below.

API Error Code: 110
API Error Description: Invalid user id
Error Message: Missing user cookie (to validate session user)

What's the best way to set the user cookie? Facebook Connect Maybe? I will maybe use this code somewhere inside a Facebook App and check if it works. I think its just the cookie issue now.. i also tried supplying &user_id manually but it didn't work.

This definitely won't work with http IMO, it has to be https.

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

You can specify a display parameter as seen in "Parameters" section.

```
FB.ui({
   method: 'apprequests',
   display: 'iframe',
   message: 'Your message',
   title: 'Your title'
}, function(response) {
   alert(response.request_ids);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are right. If you combine the info from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ and http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/, your url should be working... I tried it too but I also get error message...

Answer (score 0):

As Gokhan Ozturk said, You can specify ( display: 'iframe' ) for Apprequests.

For this to work you will have to provide an access token for the user:

```
FB.ui({ 
  method: 'apprequests',
  display: 'iframe',
  access_token: Users Access Token Here,
  title: 'Sample Title',
  message: 'Sample Message',
  data: 'some data here',
  filters: ['all'],
},
function(response) {
  if (response && response.request_ids) {
    alert('Request was sent');
  } else {
    alert('Request was not sent');
  }
});
```

You will also want to FB.init() through the JSDK, but you can do this without using it for controlling user access tokens and authentication,

```
FB.init({ 
  appId: 'Application Id',
  status: false,
  cookie: false,
  xfbml: false 
});
```

This has worked for me, where i use php to authenticate, while still needing access to the fb.ui functionality from the javascript sdk.

the display: 'iframe' - should work for all the dialog methods
'friends' , 'feed', 'send' etc.